# How to test appliances for energy used

Tags: electrical

My energy bill is twice (at least) as high as the neighbors with similar sized homes.  Of course the hydro co. thinks their meters are perfect.  I want to find out if an appliance is consuming much more energy than it should.  Is there a way to test?

Answer (score 4):

Appliances don't typically "consume more than they should", but their usage can effect their consumption.  Just take your A/C as an example, if your neighbours house is set to 75, and yours 70 then you will consume more electricity all other things equal.

Some big culprits to consider:

- Space heaters
- Fridge/freezer
- A/C
- Plasma TV's
- Furnace fans
- Pool pumps

There are a variety of devices that allow you to measure consumption.  "Kill a Watt" is a well known consumer device but you can also use a multimeter with a clamp for measuring current.  If you want to get fancy there are all sorts of home automation systems that can also measure consumption - a web search will give you all sorts of options.

Comment: Older clothes washers and dryers too, large inefficient electric motors. Newer appliances often have micro-processor controlled motors that only use the energy needed, rather than constant high wattage draw.

Comment: You could probably add electric water heaters to the list.

Comment: Don't know if the OP is still watching this, but one possible culprit if you have a well, which requires a pump, is a leak in your plumbing.

Comment: Dehumidifiers are both expensive to run AND somewhat notorious for defective batches and recall notices. (I had one replaced under recall, then the replacement was recalled for malfunctioning badly enough to be a potential fire hazard...)